# Padrino error launching sample_blog

Tags: padrino

I run into this error when I try to launch 'padrino sample_blog'. I installed updated versions of 'multi_json' and 'atomic' gems but I can't launch the blog and have no idea how to solve it, any help?

:sample_blog user$ padrino start

WARN: Unresolved specs during Gem::Specification.reset:

```
  multi_json (~> 1.3)
  atomic (>= 0)
```

WARN: Clearing out unresolved specs.
Please report a bug if this causes problems.

/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/padrino-core-0.9.21/lib/padrino-core/cli/base.rb:1:in `require': cannot load such file -- thor (LoadError)

```
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/padrino-core-0.9.21/lib/padrino-core/cli/base.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/padrino-core-0.9.21/bin/padrino:7:in `require'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/padrino-core-0.9.21/bin/padrino:7:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin/padrino:23:in `load'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin/padrino:23:in `<main>'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this and see if it helps:

```
gem cleanup atomic multi_json
```